# Browser errors in Ionic 2 Cordova web app (Could not XHR config.xml:)

Tags: cordova, web-applications, ionic2

Ionic 2
Cordova 7.0.1

I am getting the following errors in Chrome Dev Console. It looks like due to cordova plugins. Should I just remove the plugins which work well in the Android build? I do want the web app as well.

```
cordova.js:846 [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: 
fail @ cordova.js:846
xhrStatusChangeHandler @ cordova.js:860
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
SplashScreenProxy.js:131 [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: 
(anonymous) @ SplashScreenProxy.js:131
fail @ cordova.js:849
xhrStatusChangeHandler @ cordova.js:860
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
C:\Users\Phoenix\myappionic2\www\build\main.js:42730 DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 1103 ms
StatusBarProxy.js:23 StatusBar is not supported
C:\Users\Phoenix\myappionic2\www\build\main.js:7066 device already registered or no device id
```